# scala - swing - listener and reactions for TextField to pass data

Tags: swing, scala, listener

issue:
reaction += EditDone is not passing proper parameter that i am requesting from listener(this).

question:
am i handling passing the data to the listener or reactions incorrectly? if either, can you please illustrate the issue with an example and where exactly the issue resides?
much appreciated

desired outcome:
to process the TextField input and print the output to a TextArea

```
contents += new TextField(16)
              {
                val textField2:TextField = new TextField(16)
                {
                  val reg = "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$"
                  listenTo(this)
                  try
                  {
                    if (contents == reg)
                    {
                      reactions += {
                        case e: EditDone =>
                          if (textField2 != reg)
                          {
                            println("Please type a valid num.")
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            println("just testing print")
                            textArea.text = myFunctionToProcessTextInput(textField2).toString
                          }
                      }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      println("Please type a valid num.")
                    }
                  }
                  catch
                  {
                    case e: Throwable => println("There was an error. \n" + e.getStackTrace())
                  }

                  val button:Button = new Button("Click to process")
                  {
                    listenTo(mouse.clicks)
                  }

                  contents += button
                }
```

Comment: I am sorry. I dont understand the question. Or if you can, please provide SSCCE (http://sscce.org/)

Comment: hopefully i can clarify... 1) the reaction is not triggering the function named myFunctionToProcessTextInput... this function processes an ip addresss that the user types into the textfield and 2) printing the information that is processed to the text area... so my question is... how can i get the ip address from the textfield and execute myFunctionToProcessTextInput to print the data onto the textarea through a button click?